# how to convert an ostringstream hex string character pairs to a single unit8_t equivalent binary value

Tags: c++, hex, converters, uint8t, ostringstream

I am trying to do the following:

I have an assembled ostringstream object that contains a hex payload to be transmitted. Say, it might be

```
03125412349876543210af     (this is representing the data using hex convention in my string)
```

This string is representing 11 bytes, so for example the last byte to be transmitted is 0xaf (two characters giving me 8 bits of actual data).

I wish to read each pair of characters, for example the '03' pair of characters in the string and convert that into a uint8_t element which I will push onto a vector of uint8_t elements. Essentially I will create a new vector of uint8_t elements based on the contents of the string, then transmit the vector.

My test program below works OK for 'int' but does not give me what I want for uint8_t. Is there an elegant and/or straightforward way to do what I am trying to do that anyone can suggest?

(Note: example 3 was to see what happens if a non-hex-legal value was used. In example 1, a value like 34r0 would convert 34(hex) to an equivalent int and ignore the r and everything following it).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    // example 1: making a hex string an int - works
    std::stringstream str1;
    std::string s1 = "5f";
    str1 << s1;
    int value1;
    str1 >> std::hex >> value1;
    cout << value1 << endl; // produces 95 - perfect

    cout << "~~~~~~~~~" << endl;

    // example 2: making a hex string a uint8 - not the result I want
    std::stringstream str2;
    std::string s2 = "5f";
    str2 << s2;
    uint8_t value2;
    str2 >> std::hex >> value2;
    cout << value2 << endl; // produces 5 - not what I want!

    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;

    // example 3: using non-hex values
    std::stringstream str3;
    std::string s3 = "wx";
    str3 << s3;
    uint8_t value3;
    str3 >> std::hex >> value3;
    cout << value3 << endl; // produces w - not what I want!

    // this does not work either
    uint8_t value4;
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
    value4 = (uint8_t)value1;
    cout << value4 << endl; // produces - - not what I want!

    cout << "............." << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The output from this test program looks like the below:

```
Hello world!
95
~~~~~~~~~
5
~~~~~~~~~~~
w
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_
.............

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.022 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Example 1 works OK, but using int - this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example 2 you are extracting a `uint8_t`, 8 bits, so one `char` from the string, the `5`.

In example 3 is the same, you extract the first char, so the `w`.

For the last example, it prints a `char` (8 bits), `95` is the ASCII `-` character. If you want to show the number, `cast` the value to `int`.

```
value4 = (uint8_t)value1;
cout << (int)value4 << endl;
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, yes, thanks you are correct casting value4 to into before streaming produces 95 (the correct value). So I can do this in two steps (assign then cast). Still, I can't help thinking there should be a more elegant way to convert a hex string to bits.

Comment: Hi Manuel, yes, thanks you are correct casting value4 to int before streaming produces 95 (the correct value). So I can do this in two steps (assign then cast). Still, I can't help thinking there should be a more elegant way to convert a hex string to bits.

Comment: @Spangas I've upvoted the question because in fact, I didn't know we can convert strings from hex to other type with the `>>` operator. As an aside note, it seems the `>>` conversion will work with the right side parameter, so it takes as many bytes as they fit in the parameter: 8, 16, 32, 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Manuel for his answer. This is one way to solve the problem. I'd still like to know if there is a more elegant way to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    // example 1: making a hex string an int - works
    std::stringstream str1;
    std::string s1 = "5f";
    str1 << s1;
    int value1;
    str1 >> std::hex >> value1;
    cout << "value 1 as int: " << value1 << endl; // produces 95 int - OK but an int
    uint8_t value2;
    value2 = (uint8_t)value1;
    cout << "value 2 as uint8: " << (int)value2 << endl; // produces 01011111 = 95 or '-' - correct

    return 0;
}
```

Which produces:

```
Hello world!
value 1 as int: 95
value 2 as uint8: 95

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.022 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: `std::string s = "5f0066"; int num = std::stoi(s, 0, 16);` being `16` the base you want to convert from. There is also [other](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) converters to longer values.